# Acquiring Widget's state to not build it again

Tags: flutter

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-page-route-transition-9ef5c1b32823) to create [this cool route transition](https://miro.medium.com/max/320/1*5PIKSynhS-fImK8WikmBSQ.gif).

As far as I understand, the exit widget is rebuilt every time there is a route change, so it's state (for example scroll position) is not preserved. is there any way to preserve this state?

I tried using GlobalKey() and it seems to be working, but when the page changes, the exit widget is just a blank white screen for a millisecond before actually being the exit screen.